# What does || mean in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I found that there is a `||` in list manipulation. What does the `||` mean? Are there any examples about `||`?

```
lists:sum([A*B || {A, B} <- Foo]).
```

Answer (score 28):

It is used in [List comprehensions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html). List comprehensions is a shorter way to create lists without having to use funs, maps or filters.

From [Programming Erlang](http://pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang):

If we have a list L:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5].
```

And we want to double every element, we can do:

```
lists:map(fun(X) -> 2*X end, L).
```

But with List comprehensions we can do:

```
[2*X || X <- L].
```

Answer (score 11):

Nomenclature most likely comes from mathematical notion of sets, where || means "such that".

e.g. [copied from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)

F = {n2 − 4 : n is an integer; and 0 ≤ n ≤ 19}

In this notation, the colon (":") means "such that", and the description can be interpreted as "F is the set of all numbers of the form n2 − 4, such that n is a whole number in the range from 0 to 19 inclusive." Sometimes the vertical bar ("|") is used instead of the colon.

Applying same thing to

```
lists:sum([A*B || {A, B} <- Foo]).
```

means:- generate A*B such that A and B belong to list of tuples "Foo"

Comment: Yes. Mathematics uses that symbol in set comprehensions, which differ from list comprehensions in programming languages only in that the latter have a definite ordering, due purely to the sequential nature of computation. In a language with lazy evaluation, the difference between set and list comprehensions can be blurred, but Erlang doesn't have lazy evaluation baked into its core, unlike, say, Haskell.